# Curvature of orthogonal distribution in a Riemannian principal space

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry, connections, principal-bundles

Let $P \to M$ be a principal $G$-bundle and $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$ be a $G$-invariant Riemannian metric on $P$. We have an Ehresmann connection for this bundle defined by $${\rm Hor}_p(P) \doteq {\rm Ver}_p(P)^\perp,$$for any $p \in P$. So the projection $TP \to {\rm Ver}(P) \to \mathfrak{g}$ defines a connection $1$-form and so we may consider the associated curvature $2$-form $\Omega = {\rm D}\omega$, where ${\rm D}$ stands for the exterior covariant derivative given by the connection. I'd expect $\Omega$ to be somehow related to the Levi-Civita connection $\nabla$ of $\langle\cdot,\cdot\rangle$, or to the $\nabla$-horizontal connection on the vector bundle $TP\to P$.

> In a very broad sense, I think my question is: how to compute $\Omega$?

I guess I'm just a bit stumped about how to concretely use the definition of ${\rm Hor}_p(P)$ as an actual orthogonal complement. I'd like to see how this particular situation is treated or, if you know a reference I can look at, I'd be happy enough (I have already skimmed through Kobayashi and Nomizu, before you suggest it -- unless I actually missed it and you have a specific page in mind). Thanks.

Comment: Have you worked out the case of the principal $H$-bundle $G\to G/H$? The computation is illuminating for that. ($SO(3)\to S^2$ and $S^3\to S^2$ are good examples.)

Comment: Not yet, I'll take a look. Thanks!

Comment: I went over the case of $G \to G/H$ and cried to my advisor about this orthogonal distribution case last week. He said, from what I have gathered, that there's no reason to expect anything interesting in general since things can be very arbitrary (as in one could start with any smooth $G$-invariant metric only on the vertical spaces, choose the horizontal spaces arbitrarily, pull any metric from $M$ back to the horizontal spaces and declare the horizontal spaces and the vertical spaces to be orthogonal). Then something about a holonomy property... but by then I was like a dog watching tv.

Comment: I guess I had in mind (for my examples) starting with the bi-invariant metrics on the total space, which then lead me to take advantage of the symmetric space structure on the quotient. I'm not trying to think of the arbitrary general case.